# Javascript Convert text to bold unicode charset

Tags: javascript, unicode, unicode-string

I would to convert text to unicode bold format.

I found

- [U+1D5D4 - U+1D5ED] as BOLD CAPITAL [A - Z]
- [U+1D5EE - U+1D607] as BOLD CAPITAL [a - z]

How can I convert text to BOLD CAPITAL with unicode?

Thanks

Comment: why not use font weight to achieve this? or are you looking for a JS solution only?

Comment: Yes, I would generate unicode text that I can paste

Answer (score 8):

Here is a quick code snippet which does what you are asking for:

```js
let text = "This is a text: ABC";
function translate (char)
{
    let diff;
    if (/[A-Z]/.test (char))
    {
        diff = "".codePointAt (0) - "A".codePointAt (0);
    }
    else
    {
        diff = "".codePointAt (0) - "a".codePointAt (0);
    }
    return String.fromCodePoint (char.codePointAt (0) + diff);
}
let newText = text.replace (/[A-Za-z]/g, translate);
console.log (text);
console.log (newText); // -> "   : "
```

References:

- [String.prototype.codePointAt() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt)
- [String.fromCodePoint() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint)
- [String.prototype.replace() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: Hi, just made your snippet runnable - you can reach a live snippet editor (with HTML+CSS+JavaScript support) using the `[<>]`-like button

Comment: @tevemadar Thanks for the edit and for the information about the live snippet editor. I must confess I never noticed the [<>]-like button before; I'll definitely use it from now on...

Answer (score 0):

A regex-free answer inspired by [@Albert Stein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12032550/albert-stein) solution:

```js
const upperDiff = "".codePointAt(0) - "A".codePointAt(0);
const lowerDiff = "".codePointAt(0) - "a".codePointAt(0);

const isUpper = (n) => n >= 65 && n < 91;
const isLower = (n) => n >= 97 && n < 123;

const bolderize = (char) => {
  const n = char.charCodeAt(0);
  if (isUpper(n)) return String.fromCodePoint(n + upperDiff);
  if (isLower(n)) return String.fromCodePoint(n + lowerDiff);
  return char;
};

const bolderizeWord = (word) => [...word].map(bolderize).join("");

console.log("a" + bolderize("a"))
console.log(bolderizeWord("Bold") + " move")
```